# Need clarification between JSON and java map

Tags: json, arrays, dictionary

I'm developing an app in android.
I have to build an API in PHP which serves the following JSON

```
[{"id":"1","number":"2"},{"id":"3","number":"4"},{"id":"5","number":"6"},{"id":"7","number":"8"}]
```

I am completing the part of the connection in php(web server) with httpClient, and saving it to string.
Now I want to save it in a local collection (I use hashmap!!!don;t know if this is the best!!!!any suggestion is welcome).Because my jsonobject defined of array i want declare the following : `HashMap<Integer, LinkedHashMap<String, String>> hashmap;`
General idea was to save in `integer` an index,and in `LinkedHashMap<String, String>` every jsonobject. a instance of hashmap i want to be something :

```
hashmap[0] = {"id":"1","number":"2"}
hashmap[1] = {"id":"3","number":"4"}
hashmap[2] = {"id":"5","number":"6"}
```

The code that fail:

```
JSONObject tempjson;
        hashmap = new HashMap<Integer, LinkedHashMap<String,String>>();
        LinkedHashMap<String, String> linkedmap = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();      
            for(int i=0;i<jsonarray.length();i++)
            {
                JSONObject tempjsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);



                linkedmap.put("id", tempjsonobject.getString("id"));
                linkedmap.put("number", tempjsonobject.getString("id"));

                hashmap.put(i, linkedmap);

            }
```

Linkedhashmap has always the last entry --> `"id":"7","number":"8"`

But if i do the declaration of `LinkedHashMap<String, String> linkedmap = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();` inside of `for loop`    it works.

Can explain me anyone why this is happens?

Comment: Why don't you use a real JSON parsing library like http://jackson.codehaus.org?

Comment: And why don't you use an array type for JSON arrays?

Comment: Because json is too simple , array of repeated values. Although, i want to understand why linkedhasmap need to clarified inside the for loop in order to fill up the hashmap?????

Answer (score 1):

Response to the comment: "Because json is too simple , array of repeated values. Although, i want to understand why linkedhasmap need to clarified inside the for loop in order to fill up the hashmap?????"

Old question, but just for the sake of having an answer for it.
The easiest way i can think of starting to answer the question is by this sample code:

```
    public static void main(String...s){

    LinkedHashMap<String,String> lhMap = new LinkedHashMap<String,String>();
    lhMap.put("id", "a");
    lhMap.put("id", "b");

    //what do you think will be printed here "a" or "b" or "ab"?
    for(String key : lhMap.keySet())
    {
        System.out.print(lhMap.get(key));
    }
    //confirmation by the map size
    System.out.println(lhMap.size());
}
```

When you declared the LinkedHashMap outside/before the for-loop, you ended up with ONE instance of the LinkedHashMap (just like the sampe code above), and you kept modifying that ONE instance in the for-loop and adding it into the HashMap as if it was a new/different entry .

When you declared the LinkedHashMap inside the for-loop, you created a NEW instance every time you did an iteration, meaning the number of LinkedHashMaps you created was equal to jsonarray.length(), adding a new instance into the HashMap for every iteration.

Think that should answer your question but what the guys have said about Json parsing library and using array type for the problem you were solving stands.